I can't read super large data from BigQuery
raise exceptions.from_http_response(response)

google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 GET https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/project_name/queries/x?maxResults=0&location=US&prettyPrint=false: Response too large to return. Consider specifying a destination table in your job configuration.
query = """x"""

from google.cloud import bigquery
query_job = bq.query(query)

# Wait for query execution
query_job.result()

I am using dataproc to read the data from bigquery, do some transformation and then write it to bigquery.
Why I am getting this error?

Hello.  Maybe have a read of the following article:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
and contrast what is written there with the content of your question.  Maybe your question could be improved?
How much data are you anticipating would be returned?

Does this answer your question? Google BigQuery unable to process larger result set getting "Response too large to return" or "Resources exceeded during query execution"

As it says, you can save the output in BigQuery and then use BigQuery storage API to download it to Python environment
